# Extracting text between tags

Tags: regex, perl

I have been working on a script to pull out useful commands from some documentation and after searching online and playing with a few examples still can't seem to get the regexp working correctly.  The input file will be a word doc and I will need to extract some basic header info which I have working fine as well as all text between 2 sets of opening and closing tags which can span multiple lines and occur multiple times.  Below is the code I have which pulls out the header details correctly but doesn't seem to match and of the command headers through the doc.

```
open(DAT,'<input') or die "$!";
$file  = do{local $/; <DAT>};
close(DAT);
open (FH2, '>>', 'out.txt') or die "$!";
my @matches = $file =~ m/(\[$source\]|\[$target\]|\[admin\]|<IA%COMMAND>.*?       <\/IA%COMMAND>|<IA%UICOMMAND>.*?<\/IA%UICOMMAND>)/g;
print FH2 @matches;
close (DAT);
close (FH2);
```

The input file is a word doc which has a format similar to:

```
random overhead
[source]
<IA%COMMAND>stuff to print </IA%COMMAND>
stuff that should be ignored
[target]
<IA%UICOMMAND>other stuff to print</IA%UICOMMAND>
stuff to be ignored
[target]
<IA%COMMAND>print out this too
and this as well </IA%COMMAND>
```

Which should result in output:

```
[source]
<IA%COMMAND>stuff to print </IA%COMMAND>
[target]
<IA%UICOMMAND>other stuff to print</IA%UICOMMAND>
[target]
<IA%COMMAND>print out this too
and this as well </IA%COMMAND>
```

I broke it down to just searching for the open and close tags which matches fine but it doesn't seem to be happy with .*? to do the nongreedy match for the content between the tags.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to use the `/s` switch if you want `.*?` to match across newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s/(?:\A.*?(?=^\[[^[\]]*\](?:\n|\z)|\z)|(?<=[>\]]\n)(?!\[[^[\]]*\]*(?:\n|\z)|<[^>]*COMMAND>).*?(?=^\[[^[\]]*\](?:\n|\z)|^<[^>]*COMMAND>|\z))//gms;
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/Ot81cT)**.

Comment: That seems to work but is too generic and picks up everything in any set of tags.  The doc can contain other sets of tags with <IA%.*></IA%.*> but I'm only interested in the IA%COMMAND and IA%UICOMMAND tags.

Comment: When I updated the expression and ran it against the full input file it still seems to be having extra content that should have been filtered out.  There appear to be extra lines between one of the [$source] headers and the next <IA%COMMAND>.  I went and checked the source file and verified they weren't nested inside one of the 2 COMMAND tags.

Comment: It looks like it's mostly working, I've noticed a few spots that seem to have some of the text that was written in the output.    [oracle@ipda04]$ hostname
ipda04</IA%EXAMPLE> 
If no prompts are returned, SSH is configured correctly between poppie and ipcrtux3.
If prompted for a password for ipcrtux3, SSH is NOT configured correctly.  Review the steps in this section and re-execute any steps that are necessary.

</IA%TGT_APP_SRC_DB_SAME>

Comment: It goes to the hostname on the line and then goes to a newline for ipda04 and each sentence is seperate line with the closing TGT_APP_SRC_DB_SAME tag is on it's own line as well

Comment: line1: [oracle@ipda04]$ hostname line2: ipda04</IA%EXAMPLE> line 3:If no prompts are returned, SSH is configured correctly between poppie and ipcrtux3. line4 If prompted for a password for ipcrtux3, SSH is NOT configured correctly.  Review the steps in this section and re-execute any steps that are necessary. line5:</IA%TGT_APP_SRC_DB_SAME>

Comment: @user1401967 - Based on your comments I have updated my answer with a new solution.

Comment: That seems to have done it.  Thank you for your help with this, I was having no luck making progress on this.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=<[^/]+?>)(.+?)(?=</.+?>)`